# Height and Width of Container not changing in Tab Bar View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My height and width of the container are not changing by putting values for it. I am using Tab Bar View from where I call my widget for the medicine tab.

I want to have this view for Container where my medicine details are given

[image]

But I am actually having this on my screen, it's not changing the container's height and width by changing different values.

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:epicare/NavigBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'AddMedicineScreen.dart';
import 'HomeScreen.dart';

class MedicinesRecord extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MedicinesRecordState createState() => _MedicinesRecordState();
}

class _MedicinesRecordState extends State<MedicinesRecord> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  var _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = _tabController.index;
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Medicine",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
          ),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Homepage();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // give the tab bar a height [can change height to preferred height]
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32, right: 45, left: 45),
            height: 45,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                17.0,
              ),
              border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: const Color(0xff2f363d)),
            ),
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              // give the indicator a decoration (color and border radius)
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  17.0,
                ),
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              labelColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              tabs: [
                // first tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Medicine',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontSize: 16,
                      //color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                      letterSpacing: 0.48,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),

                // second tab [you can add an icon using the icon property]
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'History',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontSize: 16,
                      //color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                      letterSpacing: 0.48,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // tab bar view her
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [
               // Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25, horizontal: 32),
                  //height: 50,
                  //child:
                Medicine(),
                //),

                // second tab bar view widget
                MedHistory(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _selectedIndex > 0
          ? Container()
          : FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 40,
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffd4d411),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return AddMedicine();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget Medicine() {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:25,horizontal: 32),
      width: size.width * 0.80,
      height: 50,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 11, horizontal: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: const Color(0x29000000),
            offset: Offset(0, 3),
            blurRadius: 6,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Panadol',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              color: const Color(0xff232425),
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          Text(
            'Thrice a day',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 10,
              color: const Color(0x80232425),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget MedHistory(){
    return Text("Lol");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please post if you did.

Comment: @AnkitChawla i used List View for it

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try it too.

Comment: let me know if it won't work, i'll update my code here in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you are using expanded for tab bar view with one item try setting flex in expanded or any alternative. if you add more items it will become shorter and shorter. Expanded widget made this container flexible which is occupying every empty space available.